# AmCharts 4 Breaking when a series has no value

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I have a graph with two "series", only when one has value and the other does not, it breaks and has no background. How to fix it? I've tried several posts from various sites, videos and also read the documentation a lot. No example seems to work, so I don't know exactly what to do. If it has value it looks like it looks normal.

**Javascript**

```
    function initChartVendas() {
            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

            let chart = am4core.create(this.chartElement.nativeElement, am4charts.XYChart);
            chart.data = this.generatechartData();
            chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "'R$ ' #,###.##";

            // Create axes
            let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
            dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
            dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
            dateAxis.extraMax = null;
            dateAxis.extraMin = null;
            dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('day', 'dd');

            // Create value axis
            let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
            valueAxis.baseValue = 900;

            // Create series
            let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
            series.name = 'Pagos ';
            series.dataFields.valueY = 'valor';
            series.dataFields.dateX = 'dia';
            series.strokeWidth = 3;
            series.tooltipText = '{valueY.value}';
            series.fillOpacity = 0.1;
            series.tensionX = 0.8;
            series.tensionY = 1;
            series.fill = am4core.color('#5770ef');
            series.stroke = am4core.color('#5867dd');

            // Create series 2
            if (this.dataCancelados) {
                let seriesCancelados = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
                seriesCancelados.name = 'Cancelados ';
                seriesCancelados.dataFields.valueY = 'cancelado';
                seriesCancelados.dataFields.dateX = 'dia';
                seriesCancelados.strokeWidth = 3;
                seriesCancelados.tooltipText = '{valueY.value}';
                seriesCancelados.fillOpacity = 0.1;
                seriesCancelados.tensionX = 0.8;
                seriesCancelados.tensionY = 1;
                seriesCancelados.fill = am4core.color('#f96191');
                seriesCancelados.stroke = am4core.color('#fd397a');
            }

            // Add cursor
            chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
            chart.cursor.behavior = 'none';

            series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
            series.tooltip.adapter.add('x', (x, target) => {
                // @ts-ignore
                const valueY = series.tooltip.tooltipDataItem.valueY;
                if (valueY < 0) {
                    series.tooltip.background.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(4);
                } else {
                    series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color('#5770ef');
                }
                return x;
            });

            if (this.dataCancelados) {
                chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
            }
        }
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOYOh.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH5xk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the dates should be ordered. Before they were not, for example, the 20th came before the 16th. That's why the problem. My ordering solution is this (it only matters the day)

```
 chartData.sort((v1, v2) => (v1.dia.getDate() > v2.dia.getDate() ? 1 : -1));
```